# C: Trying to free malloc'd char array returned from function results in an error

Tags: c, malloc, free

I have a function to convert a short to a byte array here

```
char *GetBytesShort(short data)
{
    char *ptr = (char *) malloc(sizeof(short));
    memcpy(ptr, &data, sizeof(short));
    return (char *) *ptr;
}
```

And, in my main.c, I call the function like this

```
char *data = GetBytesShort(10);
free(data);
```

However, whenever I try to free the memory, I get an error

`First-chance exception at 0x5896586E (msvcr110d.dll) in Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.`

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

I'm using Visual Studios 2012 Ultimate edition. I've already set the language to C in Properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Compile As, but to no avail. And my files have the .c extension, and not the .cpp

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `return (char *) *ptr;` returns the first byte of `data` converted to a `char*`. I think you want `return ptr;`.

Comment: Please read about operators in C, and even more importantly, consult a beginner C programming guide. This is too basic to be asked here.

Comment: @H2CO3
I find that reading books about programming doesn't really help me. I learned Java completely through Google, starting small and building up, googling questions one by one. Now that I'm proficient in Java, I wanted to move on to try a lower level language.

Comment: @user1772510 And I learn C by googling around, me too. Nothing in my comment suggests that you need a book. You read whatever kind of guide you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
return (char *) *ptr;
```

Should be this:

```
return ptr;
```

What you were doing in your original code is dereference the `ptr`, returning the first byte of `data`, then cast that to a pointer. This means that you ended up with a pointer with an invalid address.

Comment: It's all about who's the fastest to answer. +1 for ya.

Answer (score 3):

`return (char *) *ptr;`

`*ptr` is a `char`, the value pointed by `ptr` to be precise, that you are casting back to a `char*`.

You need just to return `ptr`.